# Craft Translation Fallback

Tags: localization, elementcriteriamodel, language

I disabled translation for Spanish and it returned 404 page.

I set all my fields to translatable and By default craft translations are empty.

[image]

How can I return English by default? Using Spanish locale

[image]

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

By disabling a locale for an entry you are removing the automatically created route for this entry and locale (→ [docs for routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing)).

But what you can do, is to diable the automatic routing (uncheck "Entries in this section have their own URLs" in the section settings) and add the same routes as custom [dynamic routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) manually.

`news/{slug}` →  `news/_entry`

Those manual routes won't 404 for disabled entries and you can have some logic in your _entry.html template.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').slug(slug).first() %}

{% if not entry %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').slug(slug).locale('en').first() %}
    {% set duplicateContent = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if not entry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

I would also recommend to set your meta tags accordingly and make search engines aware of the duplicated content. I updated the code with a new variable definition, test if it is defined in your _layout main template.

Comment: Thanks! But all I wanted to do is get English translations if the Spanish translation is empty.

Comment: Yeah, so this is not what you want? I think it's the only way to get around the 404 for disabled entries. Manual routes and the `exit 404` tag is no uncommon practice in Craft!

Comment: You could also introduced a (non translated) lightswitch field, check its value in the template and if it's enabled load the default locale's content (or 404).